# Eclipse checkout from SVN shows invalid versioning 01.01.1970

Tags: eclipse, windows, svn, share, subclipse

I have a fresh workspace (empty folder) on a Windows Share (i.e. `\\myServer\myWorkspace`). I start eclipse on this workspace. Until now everything works fine.

Now I do a "Import" - "Checkout Project from SVN" and import one of my projects (using the [sublipse plugin for eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subclipse)).

[image]

The project is checked out and appears in the project explorer. BUT the SVN Version information is completely wrong, showing the date 01.01.1970:

[image]

No commit or update is possible.
When I put the workspace on a local disk like C:\MyWorkspace, the checkout is working fine.

**How can I checkout SVN project to a workspace on a Windows Share?**

Comment: SVN cares about file modification stamps. Putting your workspace on a share is also going to hurt overall performance. Don't use a share.

Comment: Hi nitind, thanks for your recommendation, but that was not my question. File modification stamps are also there on a Windows Share, so why does it not work properly (even with a slower performance) ? Thanks

Comment: @FiveO: I wouldn't be surprised if Java has difficulties with the time stamps on a share. Heck, even on local file systems there are often problems with rarer features (e.g. links)

Comment: Hi Joey, I just tested with the alternative SVN eclipse plugin "subversive" which does work without any problems. So it does not seem to be a problem of the timestamps. Because when I map a network drive to the same workspace, the svn does work.

Answer (score 0):

Subclipse gets all of its info from SVN API.  I seem to recall there is a bug in SVN when the root of the share is a working copy which sounds like it could be the case for you.  If it is, try creating a folder on the share for your working copy and move it into that folder to see if it makes a difference.